# How to add title attribute value of a span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, angularjs

I am using angular js to fetch the data and show inside a span.
Now I want to use this value as the title value of another span.
Right Now I am using the code below:

```
<span style="display: inline-block; width: 160px">{{activity.ActivityName}}</span>
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick" style="display: inline-block; cursor: pointer;" ng-click="showActivityInfo(this, activity, goal)" title='<%{{activity.ActivityName}} %>'></span>
```

The first line is correct. But when I want to add the title to the 2nd span, Its throwing exception.
Kindly help.

Comment: <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick" style="display: inline-block; cursor: pointer;" ng-click="showActivityInfo(this, activity, goal)" title='{{activity.ActivityName}}'></span> try this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
    title='<%{{activity.ActivityName}} %>'
```

With

```
    title='{{activity.ActivityName}}'
```

You are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

As @Rohit answered use expression and more to add, use `ng-attr-title` directive like `<span ng-attr-title='{{activity.ActivityName}}'>`

Comment: Thanx guys...for such a quick response. wish i could accept all the answers :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<span style="display: inline-block; width: 160px">{{activity.ActivityName}}   </span>
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick" style="display: inline-block; cursor: pointer;" ng-click="showActivityInfo(this, activity, goal)" title="{{activity.ActivityName}}"></span>
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

Below code helps you:

In HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="add_tooltip">
    <span ng-attr-title="{{title}}">Hello</span>
</div>
```

In JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
function add_tooltip($scope){
    $scope.title = "I am a tooltip!";    
}
```